# Cannot activate environment in anaconda prompt

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, activation

I input python in cmd and it shows a warning:

```
C:\Users\sky>python
Python 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 15:08:03) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I cannot use pip install any packages, I thought maybe that's the problem. So I checked the information at the link:https://conda.io/activation
and followed the instruction:

```
c:\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate base
```

It said 'system cannot find the path'. I searched for the files in that path and found two of them are named 'activate'. So I input

```
c:\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate
```

but still,'system cannot find the path'.
How to activate the conda environment? I really need some help. Thanks

Comment: I had similar issue when trying to activate my bot environment using Pycharm. Maybe you can apply the logic. Have you created any environment before? If yes, from your terminal, go to the project directory and do this .\yourEnvironmentName\scripts\activate then run it.

Answer (score 0):

In a clean Anaconda installation you should have **condabin only**, e.g.

`C:\Anaconda3\condabin`

on your system path. To activate the base environment from the command prompt you use

```
C:\> conda activate

(base) C:\>
```

This will add the following folders to your system path too:

`C:\Anaconda3;`
`C:\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;`
`C:\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;`
`C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin;`
`C:\Anaconda3\Scripts;`

Only now you you are ready to run python and import **all** your packages properly.

The same thing typically happens when you select `Anaconda prompt` from your programs menu.